# c# - Send value of button text property to text box

Tags: c#

I am making a basic calculator which uses (sender as button) to send the text property of the relevant button to the text box I am using as a display called 'calcScreen'. This means that if I press a button with a text value of '1' it should populate the text box. The build runs fine but when I press my number buttons the text box remains blank. Have I missed a setting somewhere in Visual Studio or is the code wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace Calc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private double accumulator = 0;
        private char lastOperaton;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OperatorPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char operation = (sender as Button).Text[0];
            if (operation == 'C')
            {
                accumulator = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                double currentValue = double.Parse(calcScreen.Text);
                switch (lastOperaton)
                {
                    case '+': accumulator += currentValue; break;
                    case '-': accumulator -= currentValue; break;
                    case '*': accumulator *= currentValue; break;
                    case '/': accumulator /= currentValue; break;
                    default: accumulator = currentValue; break;
                }
            }
            lastOperaton = operation;
            calcScreen.Text = operation == '=' ? accumulator.ToString() : "0";
        }

        private void NumberPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string number = (sender as Button).Text;
            calcScreen.Text = calcScreen.Text == "0" ? number : calcScreen.Text + number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you actually connect NumberPressed as event handler for your button, i.e. does the debugger hit a breakpoint in NumberPressed if you insert one?

Comment: still not sure how to do that. I'm still a novice sorry. Would I create a new event handler within button1_click for example and link it to NumberPressed? How would I do this? I thought (sender as Button).Text would receive the text property of any button pressed?

Comment: If you do not connect your NumberPressed method as an event handler for the buttons then it is never called, therefore your (sender as Button).Text is never executed. If you are even not able to check that problem with a debugger then you are better off with a full tutorial as we currently can not help you without taking some basic knowledge for granted. If you use a search engine with 'tutorial visual studio calculator' you will find plenty of tutorials walking through it ...

Comment: sorted it now thankyou. Added click event to each button linking to NumberPressed

Answer (score 0):

Yes you were right after I went into 'Events' in visual studio and linked the click event to NumberPressed it worked. Thanks for your help.